# Filter odd numbers recursively

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, filter

How would you solve the following task:
Write a recursive method which gets passed an array, filters all odd numbers and store them into an array. The returned array has to be sorted by each elements order.
You are not allowed to use any provided methods by java classes like Arrays.sort, Lists, etc. Furthermore loops are disallowed and generic well known sort algorithm applied to the result as well.

The part of filtering is easy, but I don't know how to put each element at its right place. At the moment my method only returns an unsorted array with all odd numbers.

```
public static int[] filterOdd(int[] m){
    return filterOdd(m, 0, 0);
}

private static int[] filterOdd(int[] m, int idx, int idxToPlace){
    if(idx <= m.length -1){
        if(m[idx] % 2 == 0){
            return filterOdd(m, idx + 1, idxToPlace);
        }else{
            int[] buffer = filterOdd(m, idx + 1, idxToPlace + 1);
            buffer[idxToPlace] = m[idx];
            return buffer;
        }
    }else{
        return new int[numberOfOddIntegers(m)];
    }
}
```

Is there any way to insert the odd number at its right place recursively?

Comment: "The returned array has to be sorted by each elements order." This is another way of saying that the original order of elements needs to be preserved, right?

Answer (score 0):

At the place where you do `buffer[idxToPlace] = m[idx];` you have to call another method that will return the sorted array with the current processing number added to it.

That new method can be recursive too: you know at that moment that the array you have in your hands is ordered. You just recursively traverse (for example from the end to the begin) and from the moment your element fits in (e.g. is smaller than the previous element) you can insert it and return the sorted array. If there is only 1 element (base case) you can just return it.

That way, at the end of your algorithm, the list will be sorted.

Comment: I will try this approach. How can I remember after inserting the new number that I also have to copy the other numbers which have to shifted one place to the right?

Comment: To be honest, I would first implement it with an `ArrayList` and just insert it at the right position. But what you actually _could_ do is, before the iteration, first create an array of size+1 to pass on, then move the number one place to the right and return the array with the empty spot in on every iteration. If you find a fit, you just fill the empty spot and return the full array.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not allowed to use `System.arraycopy`

This means that you need to figure out how many odd numbers you are going to have, in order to size your result properly:

```
public static int[] filterOdd(int[] m){
    int[] res = new int[countOdd(m, 0)];
    filterOdd(m, 0, 0, res);
    return res;
}

private static int countOdd(int[] m, int i) {
    if (i == m.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    int isOdd = m[i] % 2 != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    return isOdd + countOdd(m, i+1);
}

private static void filterOdd(int[] m, int src, int dest, int[] res){
    if(src == m.length) {
        return;
    }
    if (m[src] % 2 != 0) {
        res[dest++] = m[src];
    }
    filterOdd(m, src+1, dest, res);
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work for negative numbers. Furthermore I'm not allowed to use System.arraycopy...

Comment: @Vetterjack Then you need to run two passes over the array. See edit.